# Optimizing evaluation of expressions dependent on four variables and containing double summation

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to optimize my code which I use to evaluate expressions containing double summation. These expressions are dependent on 3 space variables ($r$, $\theta$, $\phi$) and time $t$ and consist of a few special functions (spherical Hankel, Bessel, etc.) and coefficients (e.g., $F_{l, m}$) that are also dependent on indices $l$, $m$ over which I perform summation:

```
Sum[((l + 1) SphericalBesselJ[l, t r] /(t r) - SphericalBesselJ[l + 1, t r]) 
     m^2/(l (l + 1) Sin[θ]) F[l, m]  BesselK[m, (t c)/(a)] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ], 
  {l, 1, lmax}, {m, -l, l}]
```

I need to evaluate such expressions for different points in the space and time -- I do it in a way that I use *Mathematica* to express the sums analytically (obtaining really huge expressions) and after that I substitute all the variables, e.g.

```
t = Table[i, {i, 1, 10, 3}];
θ = Table[i, {i, Pi/3, 2/3 π, π/3}];
ϕ = Table[i, {i, 0, π, π/2}];
r = Table[i, {i, 1, 2, 1/2}];
Points = Transpose[Tuples[{t, r, θ, ϕ}]]
```

However, this takes really long time (probably because *Mathematica* has to handle with these huge expressions). I am sure that there has to be different (and more efficient) approach. Could you give me any advice?